# UnableToOpenBlob, UnableToOpenConfigureFile, and other errors with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I recently installed image magick, and I'm trying to run the simple command:

```
    convert rose.jpg rose.png
```

When I do, I receive the following errors:

```
    convert: UnableToOpenBlob `rose.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709.
    convert: UnableToOpenConfigureFile `delegates.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/706.
    convert: UnableToOpenBlob `rose.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709.
    convert: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `JPG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
    convert: NoImagesDefined `rose.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong at this point.  Any ideas?
I downloaded the package from http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/ and I'm on OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually have a file called `rose.jpg` or did you mean to use the built-in file called `rose:`?

By the way, I have never had much success with the Cactus Lab setup and it is kind of configured for their specific purposes. I imagine you would have much more success with the `homebrew` package manager for OS X - I definitely do.

Go to [here](http://brew.sh) and copy and paste the one-line installation script and run it. Then you can install ImageMagick by simply typing

```
brew install imagemagick
```

You will also then be able to search for, and use, many other packages by doing things like this:

```
brew search opencv
brew search gunplot
brew search netpbm
```

If you encounter any problems with `homebrew`, simply call the Doctor, like this:

```
brew doctor
```

and he'll tell you what to do. If you want to remove ImageMagick, just do

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
```

Comment: I was trying to use their "rose" image (I tried it both as 'rose.jpg' and 'rose:'.  I have also tried a different command, 'convert -size 40x20 xc:red  xc:blue \ -rotate 90  -append    append_rotate_bad.gif' and I keep getting the same error messages.  I did install 'homebrew' and used their installer.

Comment: Try `/usr/local/bin/convert -size 100x100 xc:red xc:lime -append result.gif` then run `open result.gif`

Comment: I've actually been very sick lately and recently decided to use a different computer.  But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.environ["MAGICK_HOME"] = r"path_to_ImageMagick"
```